# Wouter prevent Not Found page to shown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
//Route.js

<NestedRoutes base="/logs">
      <Route>
        <LogsMainPage updateQuery={setQuery} />
      </Route>
      <Route
        path="/logs/detail"
        component={props => {
          return React.createElement(LogDetailsPage, {
            currentMainPageQuery: query,
            ...props,
          });
        }}
      />
      <Route
          path={'/:rest*'}
          component={params => <h1>Not Found {params.rest}</h1>}
        />
    </NestedRoutes>
```

```
// NestedRoutes.js
const NestedRoutes = props => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [parentLocation] = useLocation();

  const nestedBase = `${router.base}${props.base}`;

  // don't render anything outside of the scope
  if (!parentLocation.startsWith(nestedBase)) return null;

  // we need key to make sure the router will remount when base changed
  return (
    <Router base={nestedBase} key={nestedBase}>
      {props.children}
    </Router>
  );
};
```

The problem is everytime the page render it always shown `Not Found`(main content is rendered ie: LogsMainPage) even though the url is correct. Tried digging but can't found how to fix this "not found" url. Is there any guide to set this up properly?

---

I've edit the example from docs on the "help center route" I put the same code to show Not Found

https://codesandbox.io/s/wouter-demo-nested-routes-forked-qmg6q

Answer (score 0):

Fix your problem by following these steps.

1. Wrap your `/help` index page content using `Route` component.
2. Then wrap all your `/help` routes using the `Switch` component. It will make sure that only one route is rendered at a time like in React Router. (Resource - https://github.com/molefrog/wouter/blob/master/README.md#switch-)

```js
<Scope base="/help">
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/topics">
      <h1>Topics</h1>
      <p> To be announced...</p>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/how-to">
      <article>
        <h1>How it all started?</h1>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
      </article>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/">
      <div>
        These are nested routes. Relative location: <CurrentLoc />
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link href="/topics">Topics</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href="/how-to">How to use?</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </Route> {/* Wrap the index page content */}
    <Route path="/:rest*" component={() => <h1>Not Found</h1>} />
  </Switch> {/* Wrap all the help routes */}
</Scope>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/wouter-demo-nested-routes-4q9iv?file=/src/index.js

Let me know if you need further support.